# How do I designate my file drop location?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

is there a possible way to designate the location i want my will-be-dropped item/file should be? like when i drag and drop a file from my form to the desktop or Windows explorer?

Answer (score 0):

In drag and drop the drop target always decides, if the item can be dropped.

Comment: The user always decides that , but if you wish to control where the file wile be copied and still have copy file UI you could use methods from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.aspx

Comment: @user629926: Of course "the user decides where to drop", but if the drop target doesn't support the draged item, the user can decide whatever he wants to - he will never be able to drop the item! :-)

Comment: Sorry I meant user always decides where to drop and I accidentally commented on your answer instead of question.